# Table to div: adapting width

Tags: html, css

I want to do the following with div construction:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Field 1</td><td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Field 2 longest</td><td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Field 3 long</td><td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6AvMm/

the main problem is, how to do the first column as width as the longest (field 2) ? You know, tables are only for tabulary datas - and this case is clearly a layout.

Comment: table's default width is auto. It should be doing this already unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @Beneto You misunderstood his question. He's asking how this behaviour can be reproduced with divs instead of tables.

Comment: @DarkAshelin I see! Fair enough. Was wondering why he asked? lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `display:table` `display:table-row;` AND `display:table-cell;`

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/6AvMm/1/)**

Comment: Although this will work to reproduce a table-like structure, it is not a good idea to start from this logic to code your layout.

Comment: @DarkAshelin I agree with you .. this was just what John asked

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Field 1</div>
        <div class="cell"><input type="text" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Field 2</div>
        <div class="cell"><input type="text" /></div>
    </div><div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Field 3</div>
        <div class="cell"><input type="text" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.holder{
    display:table;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-width:1px 1px 0 0;
}
.row{display:table-row;}
.cell{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-width:0 0 1px 1px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K8YDC/)

Answer (score 1):

This would typically be done with floats. Using `display: table` is usually still not advised for layouts.

```
<div class="column">
   <div class="row">
     <p>Your content</p>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <p>Your content (longest field)</p>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
   <div class="row">
     <p>Your content</p>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <p>Your content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column{
    float: left;
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcY3u/4/)

This provides a lot of flexibility as you can easily adjust the amount of rows separately in each column, or simply skip the whole "row" thought and just write your content with headings in the column divs. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tcY3u/6/)

Using this method, you will have a lot more control over margins and positioning (needed for layouts), compared to the `table` method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to move away from tables because of the semantic reason that tables are not suitable for layout.  Therefore, I think you will have problems with your layout in the future if you just use `display: table-cell` and the way that property functions is changed.  I would recommend using something like the following CSS to abandon tables completely:

```
div.tr {
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px;
}
div.tr div.td {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 3px;
}
div.tr div.td:first-child {
    min-width: 35%;
}
.table {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6AvMm/6/

Comment: Agreed with the `display: inline-block` line of thinking, however your answer does not work for the specific case in this question. He wants the first row to be adaptive to the longest content, not set statically in css. In order to do this, you will need to work column-based instead of row-based.